# Notification sound not working in react native firebase v6?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm sending a notification to users it's received it but without any sound "default device sound"

I add a `sound: 'default'` in notification payload but still not works!

here's my function

```
// Send notification for user when his order is accepted "status : pendding"
exports.acceptOrder = functions.database
  .ref('/Providers/ProvidersOrders/InProgress/{providerUid}/{orderId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('snapshot', snapshot.val());
    const {userUID} = snapshot.val();

    const userRef = await admin
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${userUID}`)
      .once('value');

    const {userToken, username} = userRef.val(); // FCM user app token

    try {
      const options = {
        priority: 'high',
        contentAvailable: true,
      };
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Accepted order',
          body: `Hey! ${username}, your order has accepted we will contact with you as soon as possible.`,
          timestamp: Date.now().toString(),
          isRead: 'false',
          sound: 'default',
        },
      };

      let {sound, ...notification} = payload.notification;
      let uid = userUID;

      await admin
        .messaging()
        .sendToDevice(userToken, payload, options)
        .then(() => {
          return admin
            .database()
            .ref(`Notifications/${uid}`)
            .push({...notification});
        });
      console.log('message sent');

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    }
    return null;
  });
```

So what's the wrong here?

Comment: Same Issue I'm facing.

I've to manually enable Allow Sound From App Info > Notification.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @VinitBhavsar Uh, Its work Android 8.0.0, So we should have ask for a permission to enable it!

Comment: Can you Share sample code for that?

Comment: Actually i don't have, I'm just thinking.. try to open new question maybe we found an answer